# DD4T 2 Java java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: dd4t, java, jsp

I have a page class defined as below (I've removed all custom fields).

```
public class TwoColPage extends PageImpl {
   //TODO: metadata fields
}
```

In my JSP I have

```
<jsp:useBean id="pageModel" type="org.company.models.TwoColPage" scope="request"/>
```

When I run the page, I get the following exception

> Stacktrace:
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:574)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   root cause
>
> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dd4t.contentmodel.impl.PageImpl
>   cannot be cast to org.company.models.TwoColPage
>     org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.pages.two_002dcolumn_002dpage_jsp._jspService(two_002dcolumn_002dpage_jsp.java:120)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Should I be extending/implementing a different base class/interface or is there something else I am missing here?

I see that the `getPage` method of `PageFactory` returns interface `Page`, which `PageImpl` does implement (indirectly via `GenericPage` which is marked as deprecated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in [dd4t-java version 2.0.6](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.dd4t%7Cdd4t-parent%7C2.0.6%7Cpom). Any class you want to deserialize page data into must implement the *org.dd4t.contentmodel.Page* interface or extend the PageImpl class:

```
public class MyPageImpl implements Page {
    // Code here
}
```

The PageFactory class has two new methods:

```
<T extends Page> T getPage(final String uri, final Class<T> pageModel ) throws FactoryException;

<T extends Page> T findPageByUrl (String url, int publicationId, Class<T> pageModel) throws FactoryException;
```

So deserialising your custom objects goes like this:

```
MyPageImpl page = pageFactory.getPage("tcm:x-x-64", MyPageImpl.class);

// OR

MyPageImpl page = pageFactory.findPageByUrl("/index.hml",7,MyPageImpl.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

What it is trying to do here is downcasting, which is not really a good idea.

Simple Example:

- PageImpl is Animal
- TwoColPage is Cat
- Not all Animals are Cats, so the compiler throws an error

The problem comes from this line in `PageFactoryImpl`

```
page = deserialize(pageSource, PageImpl.class);
```

It fixes the type of Page to `PageImpl` meaning the page (Super Class) cannot be cast to my page (Sub Class)

Comment: A better solution might be to wrap the PageImpl in your custom page class.

Comment: Care to share an example? Thanks :)

Comment: On second thought, it would be nice to overload the PageFactory.getPage method:
PageFactory.getPage(String url, Type class)

That would allow you to specify your own class to deserialize into.

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what I was thinking actually. Where T implements Page interface

Comment: See https://github.com/dd4t/dd4t-2-java/issues/64

Comment: @ChrisMorgan looks like Rai answered your question below, care to mark his as the accepted answer?